# Direct printing multiple jasper reports at once

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've been trying to direct print two jasper reports, but it only prints one report, and for the other report it sends an error saying,
**net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Reports\Invoice.jasper**

The following code is my IReport connection code which I used for this operation.

```
public IReport(String filename, HashMap parameter) {
    super("Report Viewer");
    setIcon();

    try {
        DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
        JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
                "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, parameter, DatabaseService.getConnection());

        JasperPrintManager.printReport(print,false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

finally I called this in another class

`IReport showme = new IReport("Reports/Invoice.jasper", param);
 IReport showme2 = new IReport("Reports/Bill.jasper", param,"text");`

Comment: To ask the obvious, does the file `Reports/Invoice.jasper` exist?  What happens when you just try to create a Jasper report for `Invoice.jasper` alone?  Does it print?

Comment: Yes it prints the other report when it prints alone. seems like at once it prints only one report.

Comment: Are you sure that your database connection is being properly handled?  This could be failing after the first report is generated.

Comment: this is the database connection code I used for this purpose, ` public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (c == null) {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionstring = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbhost + ":" + dbport + dbname;
            c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionstring, dbuser, dbpassword);
            return c;

        } else {

            return c;
        }

    } `